# Passing a Task instance to the task's delegate

Tags: c#, callback, task, task-parallel-library

I have a long running Task that uses callbacks to feed data incrementally (rather than a single ContinueWith() callback at the end).

I want to be able to pass the Task object back in this callback for task identification purposes (using Task.CurrentId)

However, I cannot work out how to pass the Task object into the task delegate. There appears to be no overload to do this, and I can't use the closure to do it since the task object is not defined at that point.

eg.

```
public Task StartDoingSomeStuff(CallbackDelegate callback)
{
    Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
         while(whatever)
         {
             var results = DoSomeStuff();
             callback(results, task); //CS0165. How do I get hold of the task?
         }
    });

    return task;
}
```

gives:

> error CS0165: Use of unassigned local variable 'task'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Split declaring the variable and assigning the task to it into two statements. Make sure that you don't use the variable before the task has been assigned:

```
public Task StartDoingSomeStuff(CallbackDelegate callback)
{
    var gate = new object();
    lock (gate)
    {
        Task task = null;
        task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            lock (gate)
            {
                while (whatever)
                {
                    var results = DoSomeStuff();
                    callback(results, task);
                }
            }
        });
        return task;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 I was just writing the same thing. :) I would also move `signal.Wait();` to the line after `DoSomeStuff()`, to delay locking.

Comment: Instead of a `ManualResetEventSlim signal` it's probably better to simply use a `lock` statement. I've changed my answer accordingly after @Groo commented.

Comment: agreed, it's simpler. I would still probably lock only the `callback` line, but the performance difference is minimal.

Comment: The `callback` line is in a loop, so the `lock` would need to acquired repeatedly instead of just once.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to create a task key and a dictionary mapping keys to tasks, then pass the key as state to the task action:

```
var taskMap = new Dictionary<object, Task>();
var taskKey = new object();
taskMap.Add(taskKey, Task.Factory.StartNew(key => { callback(results, key); }, taskKey));
```

of course you then have to look up the task from the key, which may or may not suit your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

This should work although it is bad practice:

```
public Task StartDoingSomeStuff(CallbackDelegate callback)
{
    Task task = null;

    task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
         while(whatever)
         {
             var results = DoSomeStuff();
             callback(results, task); //CS0165. How do I get hold of the task?
         }
    });

    return task;
}
```

Comment: If you synchronize like [dtb did](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8575136/69809), then it's fine. This way you risk a race condition, it the background thread does its work before `task` is assigned.